# Sony WF-1000XM4 is not working

Tags: sound, bluetooth, sony

I bought a new pair of Sony WF-1000XM4. They are detected as LE_WF-1000XM4 on Ubuntu and I can pair them (status connected on the screenshot), but the sound doesn't go through them. They aren't recognized as headphones (top right on the picture is using speakers instead of headphones).

The WF-1000XM4 are not connected to any other device and the bluetooth of my computer is working with my mouse.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that for this kind of devices Ubuntu can only find the LE frequency, you'll need to set the earphones into pairing mode.

For the WF-1000XM4 you'll need to tap both ear pieces for 7 seconds and the device "WF-1000XM4" will appear on the devices list.

Answer (score 1):

If your earbuds retain pairing information from past connections with devices, they will not enter pairing mode automatically. Instead, you will need to manually initiate the setup process.

Source : https://www.audiogrounds.com/pair-sony-wf-1000xm4/

Hope this helps.